# How to convert Web application to Android app

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-apps-script

I have created the login page using google app script with session storage, i tried to convert to android app but when i try to login submit the login button it's automatically redirecting with browser. i need to countinue with android app...

```
package com.example.prn_update;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);

        myWebView.loadUrl("https://script.google.com/macros/xxxxx/exec");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a webview client.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient())
```